# Pandas extract data into a string from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     IP               Service           Status     CPU        Memory
0   10.58.1.73   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 22%   memory: 11%
0   10.58.1.99   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 25%   memory: 37%
0  10.58.1.114   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 39%    memory: 2%
0   10.58.1.82   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 50%   memory: 96%
0   10.58.1.53   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 29%   memory: 36%
0    10.58.1.1   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 54%    memory: 6%
0   10.58.1.15   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 28%   memory: 30%
0    10.58.1.4   service: StorageService   null    cpu: 5%   memory: 48%
0   10.58.1.69   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 21%   memory: 57%
0    10.58.1.5   service: StorageService   null    cpu: 4%    memory: 2%
0  10.58.1.136   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 98%   memory: 74%
0   10.58.1.43   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 36%   memory: 23%
0    10.58.1.6   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 61%   memory: 25%
0  10.58.1.137   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 76%   memory: 66%
0   10.58.1.83   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 92%   memory: 35%
0   10.58.1.39   service: StorageService   null   cpu: 35%   memory: 17%
```

I need to extract the CPU column into a string. I have tried using this command:

```
cpu = df2.CPU.str.extract(r'([\d]+))', expand=False)
```

But I think my RegEx is off. What's the best way of approaching this?

Comment: Did you mean to tag `python` rather than `pyth`?

Comment: Can you share expected output, please?

Comment: Instead of saying *"I think my RegEx is off"*, it's much clearer to show the error you got: `re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 7`. Which pretty much tells you have unmatched parentheses in the regex, and even tells you where. This was just a simple typo.

Answer (score 2):

Considering a common `cpu:` prefix - simple replacement will do the job:

```
df2.CPU.str.replace('cpu: ', '').str[:-1]
```

or even simpler with *slicing*:

```
df2.CPU.str[5:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you where the slight error in your regex is, one unwanted extra right-parenthesis:

```
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 7

df.CPU.str.extract(r'([\d]+))', expand=False)
                            ^
```

You meant to type:

```
df.CPU.str.extract(r'([\d]+)', expand=False)
```

which works fine.